# Python - Missing modules in NumPy?

Tags: python, numpy, module

I went to execute a program I'd written today and I got the following issue:

```
C:\WinPython>python iterations.py
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "iterations.py", line 18, in <module>
import numpy

File "c:\users\george\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 168, in <module>
from . import add_newdocs

File "c:\users\george\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
from numpy.lib import add_newdoc

File "c:\users\george\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
from .polynomial import *

File "c:\users\george\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\polynomial.py", line 19, in <module>
from numpy.linalg import eigvals, lstsq, inv

File "c:\users\george\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\__init__.py", line 50, in <module>

from .linalg import *
ImportError: No module named linalg
```

As I understand it, this means Numpy is looking for a specific definition, in this case numpy.zeros, but it is unable to find it.

However, I haven't changed any locations since the last time I used numpy successfully, so I'm not sure what could be causing it.

I'm using WinPython and have tried reinstalling it, but I get the same error.

Also, it can't be caused from incorrect syntax or other mistakes in my code as I get the same issue from programs that I haven't touched in weeks that worked perfectly.

Any ideas of how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have two Python installs? It kind of looks like one Python install is trying to use another one's files.

Comment: Try running the script with the Winpyton Command Prompt (should be in this directory, I don't know the exact name). The program `python` links to another distribution (canopy), as Winpython does not install/link anything by default, see [Winpython: Portable or not, the choice is yours!](https://winpython.github.io/#portable)

Comment: user2357112 - I did, and I removed the folder, but I'm still getting the same error in the standard command prompt.

sebix - I've tried your method and it seems to be working.

Thank you both for the help!